# How to move an image with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, variables, positioning

I'm having trouble getting this image to move to the right can anyone help ive just started scripting and I am finding it very confusing.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;">
<img id="tank" style="position:absolute;"src="tank.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var change = document.getElementById('tank').style.left = '0';

while(change < 200)
{
change++;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you want it to move ? Are you trying an image slider or a carousel ?

Answer (score 3):

There are many things wrong with that script...

First of all, you are attempting to set an integer as a CSS length - non-zero lengths require a unit, which you are not providing.

Second, primitive values are not passed by reference just because you want them to. Objects, however, are. So you could keep track of `document.getElementById('tank').style` and change its `left` property to move the image.

Third, the browser won't redraw the page while a script is running, meaning that if you got the script to move the image, it would immediately be at its end position (you won't even see it at the start position due to the script being run instantly).

I think that about covers everything you've done wrong. Now here's how to do it right.

```
(function() {
// don't leak variables into the global scope - think "variable = carbon dioxide"
    var elem = document.getElementById('tank'), pos = 0,
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            pos++;
            elem.style.left = pos+"px";
            if( pos == 200) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the animation you need to change the style property in a timer... something like

```
var thank = document.getElementById("thank");
var x = 0;

setInterval(function(){ thank.style.left = x + "px"; x++; },
            20); // 20ms = 50 frames per second
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is not what you are looking for at all, it will do all it's work immediately or if the condition is always true, then it will
freeze your page because it's an infinite loop.

You could use `setInterval` instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var left = 0, //Work with actual number type
    tank = document.getElementById('tank'),
    timerId = 0;

timerId = setInterval( function() { //This function is called by the browser every 33 milliseconds
    if( left++ > 200 ) {
        clearInterval( timerId ); //Stop the interval because left is > 200
    }
    tank.style.left = left + "px"; //Only convert to number + "px" when we need to set .style.left
}, 33 );
</script>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Vhpc9/

Answer (score 0):

```
var change = document.getElementById('tank').style.left = '0';
```

add "px" after your value and also have some bigger value than 0 (like 200) in order for changes to be visible.

`var change = document.getElementById('tank').style.left = '200px'`;

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
var image = document.getElementById('tank');
var change = 0;


setInterval(function(){
image.style.left = change+"px";
change+=5;
if(change>200){
clearInterval();
}
},50);
```